# Facet filtering in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a requirement, wherein I want to display facets starting with a particular sequence of characters. Can this be done ?

e.g.:

If my `search:search` returns following facets

```
<search:values-response name="facet" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<search:distinct-value frequency="846">DMPK</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="323">TNF</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="301">IL6</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="297">PAGE4</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="296">INS</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="291">PSD</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="280">EGFR</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="271">PAGE3</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="270">PAGE5</search:distinct-value>
<search:distinct-value frequency="268">CD4</search:distinct-value>
<metrics xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
<values-resolution-time>PT0.012602S</values-resolution-time>
<total-time>PT0.014218S</total-time>
</metrics>
</search:values-response>
```

I want further filter the facets by saying only get me all the facets starting with say `PAGE`. I cannot apply the filter after I got all the facets as the facets can be in 1000's. So, I want to apply the filter while getting the facets itself. Can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a [custom constraint](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_49750) with a [custom facet function](https://docs.marklogic.com/8.0/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_16978). Out of the box, facets are based on direct value comparisons only, not wildcards. Your custom constraint would be pretty boilerplate (see the documentation examples), and your facet function would perform the wildcarding:

```
declare function my:start-facet(
  $constraint as element(search:constraint), 
  $query as cts:query?, 
  $facet-options as xs:string*, 
  $quality-weight as xs:double?, 
  $forests as xs:unsignedLong*) 
as item()*
{
  cts:element-value-match(
    xs:QName("my:element"), "PAGE*", 
    $facet-options, $query, $quality-weight, $queries)
};
```

Comment: I am using `search:values` to get the faceting as I need the facets to be paged. how can I use the custom constraint on this ?

Comment: @Ravi `search:values` and custom constraints are different features. You could use a solution similar to @grtjn's with buckets in `search:values` to get something similar to what you want, but it's not customizable.

Comment: Hmm.. I don;t think buckets will work as when I want say `PAGE*`.. I want the facets to be only `PAGE1 10`, `PAGE2 15` etc.. and ignore all other facets which do not start with `PAGE`.. I think I need to rethink my UI design -- Thanks for suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If you know the starting characters upfront, you could use buckets in your search constraint definition such as:

```
<bucket name="PAGE" ge="PAGE" lt="PAGF">PAGE</bucket>
```

See also http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_80046

For getting them in a more dynamic fashion, you would need a custom constraint as mentioned by wst.

HTH!

Comment: I think I will rethink my UI design and have paging of facet and filter of facets separated out... But I will use your [ml-constraints](https://github.com/grtjn/ml-constraints) code, and modify a bit to fit my needs -- Thanks for the suggestion